# Oracle 12c database architecture

Tags: oracle, database-design

We need a suggestion on creating Oracle database for below scenario.

Suppose we want to implement multiple B2C insurance products(for e.g., motor insurance, health and travel insurance etc..) where end user can get the quote and buy an insurance online through web application. There are some master data which can be same for all different products and need to be shared across products.

How should we design the database in Oracle 12c for this scenario? Should we create single database(single SID) containing all products data or should we create multiple database on same server(multiple SID) where one database represent one product? What can be the pros and cons of both the design?

Comment: It depends on  how much data is common & common business logic. I guess  this product will have more common data  like customer info , product information, common business logi , like buying, expiry , notification  and so on ..  for me it looks like single DB is good.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ramki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scenes we'd like to see: Unlikely exam questions. *A goodly proportion of all the problems in enterprise IT these days is due to too many databases. Discuss.*

A fair chunk of your application's data will be common to all products. Not just reference data but transaction data too. The data model for any given product will be highly similar to the data model for all the other products. Likewise lots of the business rules and application code will be the same for all products.

And that's even before we consider the issue of data analysis (which is quite a hot topic these days). How easy will it be to cross-sell products to a Customer if their policies and details are in separate databases?

So do yourself a favour and build a single database.